# Show pop up when clicked on the button using ant design

Tags: typescript, button, popup, antd

```js
<div
              className="card"
              onClick={() => {
                setSelected('has production resumed');
                props.setView('downTime');
                props.startTimer();
              }}
              style={{ opacity: props.downTime ? 0.5 : 1 }}
            >
              <div style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'space-evenly' }}>
                <img width="50%" src={clockIcon} alt="Downtime" />
                <div> &nbsp;</div>
                <div
                  style={{
                    fontSize: '24px',
                    fontWeight: 600,
                    display: 'flex',
                    flexDirection: 'column',
                    justifyContent: 'center',
                  }}
                >
                  {props.downTime
                    ? new Date(props.timeStamp).getHours().toString().padStart(2, '0') +
                      ':' +
                      new Date(props.timeStamp).getMinutes().toString().padStart(2, '0') +
                      ':' +
                      new Date(props.timeStamp).getSeconds().toString().padStart(2, '0')
                    : 'Downtime'}
                  <br />
                  <div style={{ width: '140px', fontWeight: 400, fontSize: '16px', color: '#73757B' }}>
                    {props.downTime ? 'downtime' : '0h 0m'}
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

This code will give an onclick button known as download which when clicked will take us to a new page with other functionalities.
Now, I want to add a pop up window on clicking the button with a text and ok, cancel buttons on it.
`[Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PKxmG.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You can use antd `Popconfirm` component. [Popconfirm](https://ant.design/components/popconfirm). You just need to wrap your `Downtime` button with Popconfirm.

Comment: @Muhammad Nouman Rafique I have already tried with popconfirm but its not working inside onclick. I have attached my onclick function for Download please check

Comment: Please provide complete code. I think you are using onClick of button. When you wrapped your button with PopConfirm then you should use `onConfirm` prop  of PopConfirm Component. Please follow this example [PopConfirm Basic Example](https://ant.design/components/popconfirm/#components-popconfirm-demo-basic).